# tilde and acute accents not working

Tags: macos, keyboard, osx-mountain-lion

I need some help. 
I have no idea why but today tilde and acute are not working. I checked system preference, input sources and Canadian French CSA is selected. Nothing else.

When I press alt+ç I get a tilde but I cannot use it. Same thing with the acute. Does anyone know how to fix this? It's driving me crazy!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on a Canadian French keyboard, but on International English it's  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>N</kbd>   then another letter, e.g.  <kbd>N</kbd>  to get ñ
Similar for acute,  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>E</kbd>  then  <kbd>E</kbd>  gives é.

System Prefs - Keyboard - "Show Keyboard, Emoji & Symbol Viewers in menu bar"… then from the top menu, open 'Show Keyboard Viewer' & then when you hold the alt key you'll see the 'dead' keys highlighted in orange.

[image]